# BlazorWebAssembly GetFromJsonAsync Not Serialize Child Collection

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

the question is, why when i call  a api from client side with HttClient .GetFromJsonAsync the entity dont have the child collection?. I call the api from browser and the JSON text have the collections, but on object not.

this is the code of my entities:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace excelnobleza.shared.Models.Tablas.Produccion
{
    [Table("Lineas")]
    public class Linea
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Responsable { get; set; }
        public string EmailResponsable { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Maquina> Maquinas { get; } = new HashSet<Maquina>();
        public override string ToString() => this.Nombre;
    }

    public class Maquina
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El nombre de la Maquina es requerido")]
        public string NombreMaquina { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "La Linea a la que pertenece la maquina es requerida")]
        [ForeignKey("Linea")]
        public int? Linea_Id { get; set; }
        
        public virtual Linea Linea { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and i create a controller for API, the code for return all is:

```
    // GET: api/Lineas
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Linea[]>> GetLineas()
    {
        return await _context.Lineas.Include(o=> o.Maquinas).ToArrayAsync();
    }
```

this return the JSON like:

```
   [
   {
      "Id":1,
      "Nombre":"SCHIAVI",
      "Responsable":"JOSUE TORRES",
      "EmailResponsable":"jtorres",
      "Maquinas":[
         {
            "Id":1,
            "NombreMaquina":"SCHIAVI",
            "ModeloMaquina":null,
            "TipoMaquina_Id":1,
            "TipoMaquina":null,
            "Linea_Id":1
         },
         {
            "Id":2,
            "NombreMaquina":"Titan 1",
            "ModeloMaquina":null,
            "TipoMaquina_Id":3,
            "TipoMaquina":null,
            "Linea_Id":1
         },
         {
            "Id":3,
            "NombreMaquina":"Simplex",
            "ModeloMaquina":null,
            "TipoMaquina_Id":2,
            "TipoMaquina":null,
            "Linea_Id":1
         },
         {
            "Id":4,
            "NombreMaquina":"Brazileña",
            "ModeloMaquina":null,
            "TipoMaquina_Id":8,
            "TipoMaquina":null,
            "Linea_Id":1
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Id":2,
      "Nombre":"WINDMOLLER",
      "Responsable":"ERASMO CARRASCO",
      "EmailResponsable":"ecarrasco",
      "Maquinas":[
         {
            "Id":5,
            "NombreMaquina":"WINDMOLLER",
            "ModeloMaquina":null,
            "TipoMaquina_Id":1,
            "TipoMaquina":null,
            "Linea_Id":2
         },
         {
            "Id":6,
            "NombreMaquina":"TITAN 2",
            "ModeloMaquina":null,
            "TipoMaquina_Id":3,
            "TipoMaquina":null,
            "Linea_Id":2
         },
         {
            "Id":17,
            "NombreMaquina":"Super Simplex",
            "ModeloMaquina":null,
            "TipoMaquina_Id":2,
            "TipoMaquina":null,
            "Linea_Id":2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

and the RazorCode is:

```
@page "/lineas"
@inject HttpClient client
@inject IJSRuntime js
@using excelnobleza.shared.Models.Tablas.Produccion 

<h3>Lineas</h3>
<div class="form-group">
  <a class="btn btn-success" href="lineas/create"><i class="oi oi-plus"></i> Crear</a>
</div>
@if (Lineas == null)
{
  <h3>Loading...</h3>
}
else if (Lineas.Length == 0)
{
  <h3>No se encontraron</h3>
}
else
{
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Responsable</th>
        <th>Email Responsable</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach (Linea lin_ in Lineas)
      {
        <tr>
          <td>@lin_.Id</td>
          <td>@lin_.Nombre</td>
          <td>@lin_.Responsable</td>
          <td>    
            @foreach (Maquina maq in lin_.Maquinas)
            {
              <h4>@maq.NombreMaquina - @maq.ModeloMaquina</h4>
            }
          </td>    
          <td>
            <a class="btn btn-success" href="lineas/edit/@lin_.Id">Edit</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      }
    </tbody>
  </table>
}

@code {
    Linea[] Lineas;    

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("getting Lineas...");
      Lineas = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<Linea[]>("api/lineas");

      Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(Lineas));// in this line i try to see the object string, but not have the collection
    }
}
```

But the "lin_" object  not show the collection of "Maquinas". :(

> *Edited* - **the problem has been solved**
> *on entity change the Icollection to List and set to not readonly property*

```
    [Table("Lineas")]
    public class Linea
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Responsable { get; set; }
        public string EmailResponsable { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Maquina> Maquinas { get; set; } = new List<Maquina>();
        public override string ToString() => this.Nombre;
    }
```

Comment: Where's the JSON document? Does it contain any child entities to begin with?

Comment: Use your browsers Developer Tools and explore the returned result in the network tab. Does it include the child entities? I suspect the ICollection serialization being a HashSet

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the JSON its generated by the controller, on JSON text the objects contain the child collection.

Comment: @BrianParker i add the returned text api to the question

Comment: @henocsalinas the problem is most likely due to `public virtual ICollection<Maquina> Maquinas { get; }`. That may be used by EF Core but the JSON deserializer doesn't know what to do with it. `Maquinas` is an array in the JSON document, so the property should be settable at least, and probably a `List<>` or array. Using a HashSet in a DTO is rather unusual anyway

Comment: BTW unless you want to use lazy loading, you don't need to use `virtual ICollection<T>`.

Comment: I solved the problem, first I changed the iColletcion to List, also the property was readonly, now i change to {get;set;}

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks

Comment: @BrianParker Thanks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did not spot the missing set... Well done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is caused by :

```
public virtual ICollection<Maquina> Maquinas { get; } = new HashSet<Maquina>();
```

There's no setter so the JSON deserializer can't set that property. `Maquinas` is an array in the JSON document so the best type would be a `List<Maquina>` :

```
public List<Maquina> Maquinas { get;set; }
```

The signature `public virtual ICollection<Maquina> Maquinas` is needed by EF Core *only* if lazy loading is needed. In that case EF Core generates a proxy class that overrides `Maquinas` and loads the related entities only when the client code tries to access them. The current code loads all items eagerly though

Comment: Worth mentioning here that as of C# 9 you can now maintain the right access modifiers for setters on virtual collections, by declaring the setter as `init` rather than `set`. This will allow serialization to work as expected, but will also prevent the readonly property from being overwritten by invalid code.

Comment: @Webreaper if only things were that simple. It's not enough to add `init`, libraries like EF Core, JSON serializers, Swagger, OData etc need to be updated to use it. You'd have to target .NET 6 at least which means libraries targeting .NET Core 3.1, the oldest LTS runtime, won't work.

Comment: I'm using .Net 7 preview 7 and am using `init` and everything is working, so EFCore definitely supports it already. I don't know when support for it was added, but if it wasn't before 7, then it'll be available in a couple of months. Can't speak to Swagger, OData etc as I don't use them.